# User cannot login that registers from a custom registration page In Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I created a custom register controller. The user who registers through my custom register class cannot log in, but those who register from the default register page can log in. Am I missing something for the custom registration page?

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function AdminAgentDataAdd(Request $request)
    {
        $password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $request->merge(['password' => $password]);
        $request->merge(['role' => 3]);

        $DataAddCheck = User::create($request->all());

        if ($DataAddCheck) {
            return back()->with('successMsg',
                'Agent Created Successfully');
        } else {
            return back()->with('successMsg',
                'Something Went Wrong Try Again!');
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The user creates successfully in my DB.

Comment: Do `return $DataAddCheck` before the **if statement** or dd() it and share the results

Comment: Share the login's logic too

Comment: please check https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/22686541?key=bc330cf363afa9949abb3a579354ea0a @medilies

Comment: I use the Default login provided by Laravel breeze @RiliwanBalogun

Comment: Everything seems correct. check this tool https://phppasswordhash.com/ this hash `$2y$10$26znb8UsrU6FYtSFB/ScHOt/WUr57X7ThUM1wERPyP/MoxGleaS4S` is the string `password` try to put it manually in the database and authenticate with it

Comment: it's works perfect @medilies

Comment: Then the issue is in the process of hashing the password and storing it

Comment: Yes my registration page hashing may not work properly

Comment: Is there any other way to hash or need to add some other function for having? @medilies

Comment: Side note merging new values into `$request` do not seem very clean. I prefer `User::create([
'name' => $request->name,
'email' => $request->email,
'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
'role'=>3,
'phone'=>$request->phone,
])` **copied from Breez**

Comment: Post This ANS for future developer @medilies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how **laravel/breez** does the registration

```php
// After the validation

$user = User::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    // fields you added
    'role'=>3,
    'phone'=>$request->phone,
]);
```